# looping a function that uses Ajax. Fails in IE only. Every other browser works

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer

This javascript I have is supposed to be very simple. It is, but IE is not making it at all. I have made 2 posts on here trying to get this fixed and NOTHING. I have been working on this for 2 weeks. I've googled everything, I've used debugger a million times and NOTHING. What I'm trying to do is have a function that calls a php file on my website that gets the percent of the file being uploaded. So It uses ajax to call the page and get the custom header that gives the percent and then that changes the width of a div element. Simple right? Well IE is stuck at 0% at all times, on all versions of IE (including 9).

Here is the script: http://pastebin.com/RBLygM9H

I have read that it could be because of the way I am calling the function initially. It is called like this:

```
onchange="checkForm(this.form, 'This is a just a random ID');"
```

I used the watch function with IE debugger and paused it and checked if the function is even getting the proper variables and it is. I also checked the headers and it only sends one header at the beginning and never does it again. Whenever I pause the debugger is always stops at this:

```
setTimeout(function(){ prog_bar(upload_id); }, 1000);
```

yet it never claims it as an error, it's only when I pause it. I checked the Console tab, Breakpoints, Locals, Watch and Call stack there is nothing in them except for Call Stack. All it says is Anonymous function and gives me no more information. Also, I have got it to change percents before but I have no idea what caused it and its happens randomly. Also I have getting this error before:

> The breakpoint is not valid. no executible code is asossiated with this line.

I'm not quite sure what is means but I was never able to replicate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Recode this using JQuery or some other framework, it really does
   help.
2. Try inserting some alerts, see where stuff actually
   happens.
3. It's IE, add some form of cache breaking, by using datetime http://blog.4webby.com/posts/view/10/ajax_how_to_prevent_ie_from_caching_ajax_get_requests

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
1. I'm not the biggest javascript person and never use Jquery before but ill see. 
2. I did try using alerts and everything worked... its soo weird...
3. I will check this out thanks.

Comment: ....My god I believe you found it! So it just stupid IE caching everything. Really microsoft? Make less of a fail browser next time. Check mark for you! :)

Comment: Be happy to help you with Jquery if you want it, thomas.p[[remove]].andrews@gma[[remove]]il.co[[remove]]m
Feel free to send me an email.